# Play framework doesn't see SSL Intermediate/chain certificate

Tags: ssl, playframework, netty

I've created JKS keystore with 6 entries:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in myapp.cert -inkey myapp.key -name myapp.pl -out myapp.p12
keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore myapp.jks -srckeystore myapp.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
keytool -import -alias bundle -trustcacerts -file az.pem -keystore myapp.jks

keytool -list -keystore myapp.jks
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 6 entries
```

When I run it on my server it doesn't see any intermediate chain certificates. On some computers, it works properly as it has all certificates, on other shows:

```
The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER
```

I've checked using online tool and it sees my certificate but the problem is with intermediate chain certificates.

My configuration:

```
play {
  crypto.secret="%APPLICATION_SECRET%"

  # Certyficate SSL
  server.https.keyStore {
    path = "/etc/bodyfit-server/myapp.jks"
    type = "JKS"
    password = "12345678"
  }
}
```

I use play framework 2.5 and Netty, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, after converting to PKCS12 format it works as it should

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore myapp.jks -destkeystore myapp.p12 -srcstoretype JKS - deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass *******
```

Of course, in the configuration, you have to change key format